# If $H\leq G$ ($H$ not normal), prove there exists $x' \in Hx$, $y' \in Hy$ such that $x'y' \notin Hxy$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> If $H\leq G$ ($H$ not normal), prove there exists $x' \in Hx$, $y' \in Hy$ such that $x'y' \notin Hxy$

What I've tried is:

Let $x' \in Hx$, $y' \in Hy$, then $x'y' \in HxHy$. We have to see that $HxHy\neq Hxy$. $HxHy=Hxy$ iff $HxHy(xy)^{-1}=HxHx^{-1}=H$ and I don't know how to continue with it.

I don't know if I'm doing this in the correct way or no. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd try to prove the contraposition.

Comment: Ok, I think I've got it

Answer (score 1):

Suppose to the contrary that there does not exist $x' \in Hx$, $y' \in Hy$ such that $x'y' \notin Hxy$.

Let $g\in G$ and $h\in H$.
Note that $g\in Hg$ and $hg\in Hg$.
By the assumption we must have $ghg\in Hg^2$.
This means that $ghg=h'g^2$ for some $h'\in H$.
Thus we get $ghg^{-1}=h'\in H$.
This shows that $H$ is normal; a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a direct constructive proof that uses the witness for non-normality of $H$.

If $H$ is not normal, there exists $x\in G$ and $h\in H$ such that $xhx^{-1}\notin H$. Set $y=x^{-1}$. Consider $x’=x\in Hx$ and $y’=hx^{-1}\in Hx^{-1}=Hy$. Then $x’y’=xhx^{-1}\notin H=Hxx^{-1} = Hxy$.